# spatial filtering data in R between two vectors

Tags: r, vector, rgeos

I have two shapefiles in R. One contains a vector of coastline (called coastline) and the other file of parcels (called parcels). I want to filter the parcel data for only those parcels within 1 mile of the coastline.

How do I find the data only inside the 1 mile coastline radius? Assume it would be something in the rgeos package.

Comment: What feature type are the two files? I assume coastline is line strings but what about parcels? Points/lines/polygons? In general I'd say buffer coastline with a 100m radius and intersect that with parcels. That obviously depends on feature type and projection. So we would need a bit more info

Comment: @TimSalabim you mean a 1609.3 metre radius? gBuffer and gIntersects from rgeos should do it, or use `sf` and st_buffer st_intersects.

Comment: @Spacedman yes, I misread that!

Comment: @TimSalabim yes, parcels is polygons and coastline is line strings. I've done a similar project using SQL in Carto, creating a buffer and then filtering on the intersections. But this is my first crack in R.

Comment: @TimSalabim And both files are in the Web Mercator projection

Answer (score 1):

Here's a reproducible example using `library(sf)`:

```
library(sf)
library(mapview)

## web mercator proj4 string
prj = "+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs"

## convert franconia to web mercator
parcels = st_transform(franconia, crs = prj)

## convert franconia outline to linestring (our coastline)
coastline = st_cast(st_union(parcels), "LINESTRING")

## create buffer around outline
coastline_buff = st_buffer(coastline, dist = 1609.3)

## intersect polys w buffer (and cast to multipolygon)
parcels_in_coastline_buff = st_intersection(parcels, coastline_buff)
parcels_in_coastline_buff = st_cast(parcels_in_coastline_buff, "MULTIPOLYGON")

## inspect
mapview(parcels, col.regions = "green", alpha.regions = 0.1) +          ## original polygon layer
  mapview(coastline_buff, col.regions = "blue", alpha.regions = 0.1) +  ## the buffered "coastline"
  mapview(parcels_in_coastline_buff, col.regions = "magenta") +         ## the result  
  mapview(coastline, color = "black", lwd = 3)                          ## the "coastline"
```

The first two steps (st_transform & st_cast/st_union) are only necessary to create data that resembles your situation.

Comment: Thank you @TimSalabim! Will try today and let you know how we do

Comment: Got an error on the second line of code: "object 'franconia' not found"

Also, for FWIW, it looks like our coastline is in SPATIAL LINES, not sure if that is the same format as line strings. When I tried the st_buffer function I got this error: 

no applicable method for 'st_buffer' applied to an object of class "c('SpatialLinesDataFrame', 'SpatialLines', 'Spatial', 'SpatialLinesNULL', 'SpatialVector')"

Comment: franconia is a data set provided by library(mapview). If you don't load mapview R can't find it. For sp objects gBuffer and gIntersects from rgeos should do the same, as @Spacedman pointed out earlier. If you don't need to sticj with sp you could use `sf::st_read` to read you shapefiles or st_as_sf(sp_object) to convert your sp_object, then st_buffer and st_intersection should work

Comment: Right got it. Thank you! Is the franconia here the basemap? When I ran the script I got back a map in Germany...assuming that has something to do with the franconia code. For what it's worth, the parcels we're working with are in Florida.